# Why are some things defined twice in Scala's libraries?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I find some libraries for Scala (including its own library) organised in such a messy way that really bothers me and makes things hard to remember. I'm coming from a .NET background where everything is so easy to pick up and there are no "gotcha's".

One example I can remember now is when importing **Play's actor system**, it's defined two times:

- play.libs.Akka
- play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka

Why is that? and what's the difference between the two packages play.libs and play.api.libs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because some Scala libraries (including Play) have a Scala API as well as a Java one.

Example:
* [play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/concurrent/Akka.scala)
* [play.libs.Akka](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/libs/Akka.java)

I agree that Play's packages' names could be made clearer.

Comment: Why would I want the Java interface in Scala?

Comment: Because you might be writing Java code in your Scala project, or simply using the lib in a pure Java project (Play is a Java framework too).